# How can I make Chrome use the window button icons from the system style sheet?

Tags: themes, google-chrome

How can I fix it ?

Chrome button doesn't match the theme button

[image: chromebuttonfix]

Comment: As of right now, I don't know of any way to do this. I am fairly certain it cannot be done with Google Chrome's existing GTK+ integration.

Comment: Thanks everyone,problem did not improved but not very important. Have a nice day :)

Comment: I guess it's a bug in this theme, you should contact its developer.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried Google Settings (=) -> Settings -> Search GTK Theme and clicked that button?

I would also try using that "Use system title bar and borders" checkbox.

[image: Settings after searching]

Comment: Yes I have tried but did not work.

Comment: did you also do the "System title bar and borders" checkbox? it is unclicked in my screenshot.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately not changed.

Answer (score 0):

Right click in the Chrome title bar and select "use system icons".

Comment: Thanks but I do not see text like this.

Comment: It's "Use system title bar and borders", as the other answer suggests.